# Calculate if a certain color is in the same family of a given color

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, colors

How to calculate if a certain RGB value is in the same approximation of color

for example if we have the set

```
var color = {
   r : 20,
   g : 20,
   b : 80
}
```

then the same color when lit or blacked should produce approx the same ratio maybe something like

```
var colorBrighter = {
   r : 40,
   g : 40,
   g : 100
}
```

The question if anyone can think of a function or formula to check if the colors are in the same range... a way to determain if a color is a brighter or darker variation of a given color...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct computations in RGB would be very far from what the eye perceives. Don't even attempt to compute distances in this space, they mean nothing.

The usual solution when looking for simple computations that match human perception (for example finding a darker, or near color, or looking for a pair of contrasted colors) is to convert your colors to another color space.

[HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) gives very good results for that.

An excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_color_models_in_computer_graphics):

> The HSL model describes colors in terms of hue, saturation, and
>   lightness (also called luminance). (Note: the definition of saturation
>   in HSL is substantially different from HSV, and lightness is not
>   intensity.) The model has two prominent properties:
>
> - The transition from black to a hue to white is symmetric and is
>     controlled solely by increasing lightness
> - Decreasing saturation
>     transitions to a shade of gray dependent on the lightness, thus
>     keeping the overall intensity relatively constant The properties
>     mentioned above have led to the wide use of HSL, in particular, in the
>     CSS3 color model.[3](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/2121882)
>
> As in HSV, hue corresponds directly to the concept of hue in the Color
>   Basics section. The advantages of using hue are
>
> The angular relationship between tones around the color circle is
>   easily identified Shades, tints, and tones can be generated easily
>   without affecting the hue

You'll find many snippets and libraries doing the conversion (one [example](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/2121882)).

Additionally, if your goal is to set colors on DOM elements, you should consider using hsl directly as it's supported by all browsers:

```
color: hsl(120, 100%, 25%);
```

Answer (score 1):

> a formula to check if the colors are in the same range

```
  const difference = (one, two) => Math.sqrt(
    (one.r - two.r) ** 2 +
    (one.g - two.g) ** 2 +
    (one.b - two.b) ** 2
 );
```

Usable as:

```
console.log(difference(color, colorBrighter));
```

This basically calculates the distance in a 3dimensional "color room", which is (afaik) a common way to determine the difference between two colors.

> a way to determain if a color is a brighter or darker variation of a given color

If you imagine the colors as vectors, one vector has to be the multiple of another:

```
 color1 * k = color2
```

So we just have to check that equation:

```
const differOnlyInBrightness = (one, two) => (
   k => one.g * k === two.g && one.b * k === two.b
 )(two.r / one.r);
```